# Meaning of JAPAなび

Tags: usage, meaning

What is the meaning of 「JAPAなび」? The term is often used on NHK あさイチ broadcasts. Maybe 「なび」is for "navigation" here?

Comment: Maybe, Japan-navi?

Comment: No no, it's exactly as it is. I think it's some abbreviation.

Comment: Have you tried checking their website? http://www1.nhk.or.jp/asaichi/tabi/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"なび" is a shortening of "ナビゲーション" (navigation). As u may know, japanese alphabet contains only one character which begins with sound "V" and it is わ. For this reason, all "vi", "vu", "ve", "vo" become び、ぶ、べ、ぼ in japanese. For example, Vietnam - ベトナム. But for some reason violin is バイオリン (not ワイオリン).

Comment: [The /w/ sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labio-velar_approximant) in わ isn't the same sound as [the /v/ sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_labiodental_fricative) in English *navigation*.  Japanese doesn't have a /v/ sound, so /b/ is usually substituted.